# Debugger lldb says my object is nil when is not ?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, llvm

Recently I upgraded my project settings in Xcode 4.3 and now I use the latest llvm debugger: **lldb**

However (sometimes) I have the impression the debugger is not giving me the correct info? Could this be possible?

For example, The debugger says `_documentsItem` is `nil` (both in in the console and when mouse-over-ing the ivar). But I know it's **NOT**,  that is why I can see it (an UIBarButtonItem) and more important that is why the app stopped at the shown breakpoint)

```
if (_documentsItem) { ...
```

In fact most of my properties return nil too :(
Is there a way I make sure the debugger is doing fine?

[image: po object]

Comment: The debugger generally doesn't lie.  Is it possible that you have a stray semicolon, e.g. `if (_documentsItem);` ?

Comment: Check `_documentsItem` with `NSLog`.  If `NSLog` says its not nil, post your code.

Comment: NSLog says is not nil ... I went back to GDB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've met similar issues in Xcode 4.3. And press "Option" while click "run" and changed it back to stable gdb.

Comment: You are indeed true. Just for the record these is part of **Xcode 4.3 release Notes**: "Some debugger commands and log expressions in breakpoints fail when using the LLDB debugger because Xcode uses the wrong frame when executing the debugger command or evaluating the log expression.
If you know what thread the the debugger command or log expression must run relative to, add a breakpoint action that sets the current frame to the appropriate one before the breakpoint action with the problem. 10426977"

Comment: Taken from here: [Xcode 4.3 release Notes] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely nil.

Look at the address that its been allocated. 0x00000 is nil.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with XCode, which still hasn't been resolved, as of 4.3.2. Switch back to GDB, even if XCode complains about your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

For view property value, use 
"po self.yourproperty"