# Objective-C object nil after init

Tags: objective-c, lldb

Okay, I'm NOT new to `Objective-C` but I encountered a strange bug, that i have never seen before. Maybe I only made a small mistake and you're able to see it.

Within one of my functions I start by creating a new object from a custom view-class in the following way:

```
[buttonsBackground removeFromSuperview];
self.buttonsBackground = [[[PostCommentButtonsBackground alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds] autorelease];
buttonsBackground.delegate = self;
```

But if I jump with the debugger over this block, the debugger claims that `buttonsBackground` would be a nil-pointer. But adding a `NSLog` right afterwards with

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.buttonsBackground);
```

still prints the line

```
<PostCommentButtonsBackground: 0x7bd27a0; frame = (0 0; 320 82); layer = <CALayer: 0x6e688b0>>
```

which clearly means, that it can't be nil. Does anybody have an idea how this can even be possible?

I am using the LLDB Debugger, not the GDB. The property `buttonsBackground` is declared as

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)PostCommentButtonsBackground *buttonsBackground;
```

so a missing retain isn't the case either.

**EDIT:** Okay, I just saw, that i'm not the only person with the exact same problem. There's another person with the same problem [Debugger lldb says my object is nil when is not ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408219/debugger-lldb-says-my-object-is-nil-when-is-not)

I'm just leaving this post open anyway, because in the other post people kept claiming, the developer did a bad job with his memory management. In my post you can actually see, that this is not the case.

Comment: why dont consequently use self.property ? you seem to mix, that is often not a good idea.

Comment: because the self.property is only relevant for memory management and since the block above is the first thing that happens within the function, there's no danger of a local variable anyway

Comment: Have you looked at this through GDB? Might be just a bug with LLDB. I can't see anything wrong with your memory management here. (Either that or I'm constantly doing things wrong)

Comment: @Infinite: `self.property` is not just relevant for  memory management.  If you have a property, you should use it everywhere except in `-init` and `-dealloc`

Comment: @jeremyP what else should it be relevant for? For example especially within init it is even discouraged to use self. calls

But apart from that, yes it only happens in the LLDB, not with GDB. but if you use GDB, xcode keeps throwing warnings to upgrade your project to use LLDB... annooooooying

Comment: @Infinite: well if you have `@synthesize buttonsBackground = _ buttonsBackground` your code is broken.  If you want to do KVO your code is broken.  If you consider encapsulation to be important (you should), your code is broken.

Comment: Are you using ASAN? I've seen that mess up debugging...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLDB with the new Xcode 4.3 sometimes is totally lost, and using a NSLog instead of LLDB will show you that your initialized object is correctly initialized and not `nil`.

So, this is really a pain when you're in front of a bug.