# Strange behavior with NSString instance variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

Here is part of a class definition in an iOS program using reference counting (ARC):

```
@interface CapViewController : UIViewController 
{
    NSString *bottomBn;
    NSString *topBn;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bottomBn;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *topBn;

@end
```

In the implementation I synthesize them:

```
@implementation CapViewController

@synthesize bottomBn;
@synthesize topBn;
```

The problem is when I try to assign values. If I step through the following lines in a class method (first time each instance variable is being used):

```
bottomBn = [NSString stringWithString:@"bottomBn"];        
topBn = [NSString stringWithString:@"topBn"];
```

After the first line has executed, the value of topBn becomes @"bottomBn" and bottomBn is nil
The second line has no impact.

If I change the order the instance variables are defined in the class, i.e.:

```
NSString *topBn;
NSString *bottomBn;
```

then the first assignment has no effect and the second assignment results in "topBn" being assigned to bottomBn.

Using local variables it works as expected:

```
NSString *localbottomBn = [NSString stringWithString:@"defaultbottombutton"];        
NSString *localtopBn = [NSString stringWithString:@"defaulttopbutton"];
```

This seems bizarre behavior to me. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post more of the code surrounding the lines where you set them? If you could post a complete, minimal test case that could be used to reproduce the problem, that would help too.

Comment: The current version of lldb has a serious bug with displaying the values of ivars. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533189/objective-c-object-nil-after-init and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408219/debugger-lldb-says-my-object-is-nil-when-is-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problems with other types and objects (even CGFloat and CGPoint). I think the problem is in debugger. Try to print you strings instead of look variables via debugger. For me NSLog function print what I expected.

I have no ideas why debugger have this unpredictable behavior (may be it's a bug), but now I prefere "NSLog debugging". It is sad.

Comment: I cannot believe I've spent so much time on this. You're absolutely right. The values the debugger window is displaying (i.e. those posted above) are different to those outputted by NSLog. When I print via NSLog I get the exact values I would expect.

Comment: Yes, I spent a couple of hours and lot of nerves too. I faced with this problem only after last xCode update, so I think it is apples bug.

Answer (score 7):

You are not setting the autoreleased strings, you should set the strings as:

```
self.bottomBn = [NSString stringWithString:@"bottomBn"];        
self.topBn = [NSString stringWithString:@"topBn"];
```

Comment: Thank-you for the response. i made the change but the problem remained. Lloyd18's response was the solution ... the debugger/watch windows was displaying erratic values. NSLog showed the correct values. That being said, I've made the change you suggested to improve the code. Thanks!