# Strange behavior in LLDB when printing a double type struct member

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, debugging, lldb

In some iOS code, I have an C `struct` ivar on an object.  One of the members of this struct is of type `double`.  If I, within a method, assign to this `struct` member, the debugger reports spurious values for the value of this `struct` member when I print the `struct` itself (as does the list view of variables), but when I print the `struct` member directly, (`p structWithDouble.doubleMember`), I get the right value.  Furthermore, If I assign the value of this member to a local, automatic `double` var, I see the correct value in the list view and when printing.

I imagine this is an issue with LLDB, but it's unsettling and frustrating.  Is this a known issue?  If so, is there a workaround?

#### Examples

```
typedef struct {
    double doubleMember;
} structWithDouble;

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    structWithDouble structAsIvar;
}
@end

@implementation

- (void)someMethod {
    structAsIvar.doubleMember = 200.0;
    double localDouble = structAsIvar.doubleMember;
}
```

Inside `someMethod:`, the debugger variable list shows the following values:

```
structAsIvar.doubleMember (double) 1.65865e-307
localDouble               (double) 200
```

Over in LLDB, I get the following output when breaking in `someMethod:`:

```
(lldb) p structAsIvar.doubleMember
(double) $4 = 200

(lldb) p structAsIvar
(structAsIvar) $5 = {
  (double) doublemember = 1.17244e-312
}

(lldb) p localDouble
(double) 200

(lldb) p self->structAsIvar.doubleMember
(double) 200
```

#### Update

I've found that **none** of this behavior happens when using GDB.  Apparently LLDB just isn't ready yet...  I'm still be interested in a workaround for LLDB, though.

Comment: Possibly the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533189/objective-c-object-nil-after-init http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408219/debugger-lldb-says-my-object-is-nil-when-is-not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533189/objective-c-object-nil-after-init

Comment: FYI, your first and last links are the same.  I've *also* encountered this issue.  They may be related, but as opposed to the behavior in the accepted answer of the first question, `NSLog()` gives the same output as the debugger.  However, since the side effects I'm expecting are occurring, I *know* the value *really is* `200` despite what `NSLog()` or the debugger say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is fixed in Xcode 4.5's lldb (lldb-167.2):

```
(lldb)  p structAsIvar.doubleMember
(double) $5 = 200
(lldb)  p structAsIvar
(structWithDouble) $6 = {
  (double) doubleMember = 200
}
(lldb) p localDouble
(double) $7 = 200
(lldb) p self->structAsIvar.doubleMember
(double) $8 = 200
(lldb)
```

I'm not sure exactly which release had the fix; it's likely Xcode 4.4 also works correctly but I don't have that at hand to test right now.