# -[id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer] both recognizers are nil in debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I've got a method

```objective-c
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"%@\n%@", gestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer);
    return YES;
}
```

Logging is OK:

```
2013-04-12 21:36:20.126 Project[2504:907] <UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x1e5c25b0; state = Ended; view = <UIView 0x1e5c5cc0>; target= <(action=toggleControls, target=<PictureViewController 0x1e5c0ab0>)>; must-fail-for = {
        <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x1e5c53a0; state = Failed; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <ZoomScroll 0x1e5c4790>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<ZoomScroll 0x1e5c4790>)>>,
        <UIScrollViewPinchGestureRecognizer: 0x1e5c5bb0; state = Failed; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <ZoomScroll 0x1e5c4790>; target= <(action=handlePinch:, target=<ZoomScroll 0x1e5c4790>)>>
    }>
<UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x1f0bb4f0; state = Failed; view = <UIScrollView 0x1f0bb010>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1f0bb010>)>; must-fail-for = {
        <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x1f0bb340; state = Failed; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1f0bb010>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1f0bb010>)>>
    }>
```

But in debug console they are both `nil`s

```
(lldb) po gestureRecognizer
$1 = 0x00000000 <nil>
(lldb) po otherGestureRecognizer
$2 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

What's happening? Can I fix that somehow?

Comment: Can you please show the code that initializes the gesture recognizers?

Comment: Its Just very strange. Are you using po when you are inside the method? and your class doesn't have ivar's of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug with XCode / lldb that hasn't been resolved yet. If you are not running xcode 5-dp you can go back to gdb and it should work.

*Xcode 4.3 release Notes: "Some debugger commands and log expressions in breakpoints fail when using the LLDB debugger because Xcode uses the wrong frame when executing the debugger command or evaluating the log expression. If you know what thread the the debugger command or log expression must run relative to, add a breakpoint action that sets the current frame to the appropriate one before the breakpoint action with the problem. 10426977"*

My reference: [Debugger lldb says my object is nil when is not ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408219/debugger-lldb-says-my-object-is-nil-when-is-not)

Answer (score -1):

have you initialized your recognizers?

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panView:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
panRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Method is called a thousand times. And I said that `NSLog` is printing them, but they're not in the debugger console.